# Непонятное предупреждение при подписании апплета

Tags: applet, java, сертификат

При подписании апплета после сообщения, что jar подрисан, выдается еще предупреждение:

> No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date <2018-04-17> or after any future revocation date.

Дата 17.04.2018 соответствует концу срока сертификата. Что значит это предупреждение? Все в порядке или что-то сделано неправильно?

Comment: @Helena2977, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это предупреждение о том, что при подписании не указано время подписания апплета (timestamp) - подробнее [читайте в документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/time-of-signing.html).

Смысл состоит в том, чтобы разработчики не переподписывали постоянно апплеты, а подписали один раз - ну типа тогда, если известно время подписания, то подпись апплета не устареет.

Comment: Но это не имеет значения для работы апплета, он будет нормально работать пока сертификат не истечет?